# Google Universal eCommerce Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Am I doing this right? I'm just using an example with data already in it.

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this, as none of my test orders have landed into the Transactions area of Google Analytics.

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA--1', 'amleo.com');ga('send', 'pageview');
//Include the ecommerce plugin
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
//Initialize the transaction
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': 'WEBA001399736',// order ID - required      
    'affiliation': 'A.M. Leonard',// affiliation or store name      
    'revenue': '19.99',// total - required
    'shipping': '9.99',// shipping     
    'tax': '2.10',// tax
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': 'WEBA001399736',// order ID - necessary to associate item with transaction      
    'name': 'Leonard+ArborRain+Tower+-+Plant+%26+Tree+Hydrator',// product name 
    'sku': 'ART20',// SKU/code - required     
    'category': '',// category or variation      
    'price': '19.99',// unit price - required      
    'quantity': '1'// quantity - required   
});

ga('ecommerce:send');//submits transaction to the analytics servers
</script>
```

Comment: how long did you wait it takes 24 hours before it will show up in the standard report

Comment: It should show up pretty quick. Use a browser extension like [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to monitor the request when you submit a transaction.